# Technical use: "Manufacturing" vs. "Production"

Tags: word-choice, terminology

I want to know the cases when we should prefer one word over another. In other words, what are the *technical* usages of `production` and `manufacturing`?

Comment: just for fun: ***Manufacturing is the production** of some goods/products!* ^-^

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39972/production-vs-manufacturing

Answer (score 1):

Generally, *'production'* is used as a synonym for *'manufacturing'* in most contexts as they both involve creation of a new object. However, *'production'* can be used in many contexts, **within as well as outside an industry**. *'Manufacturing'*, is mostly used in an **industrial-based** context. In some cases, they cannot be interchanged. 

Manufacturing is used in sentences like :

> "There is a factory that **manufactures** spare parts around the corner."
>   "There is a factory that **produces** spare parts around the corner."

But you **do not** say:

> "This farm **manufactures** the finest milk."

Instead you say:

> "This farm **produces** the finest milk."

To know more about the difference between *'Production'* and *'Manufacturing'*, [Click Here](http://www.differencebetween.net/business/differences-between-manufacturing-and-production/).