# Differences in job titles. "Manufacturing manager", "Production manager", "Manufacture manager"

Tags: usage, vocabulary, grammaticality-in-context, collocations

I was given a piece of business card with a job title "Manufacture manager".

I wonder any differences between

a. "Manufacturing manager"

b. "Production manager"

c. "Manufacture manager"

1. Are three of these all correct？
2. What is the meaning of each of them?

It seems that the first two are used widely and commonly.

I already check the difference between the first two from [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76634/technical-use-manufacturing-vs-production).

3. But how about the third one?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the term "manufacture manager" is not common and does not have a widely understood meaning. I suspect that the business card simply contained an error. Therefore, this question is unlikely to be useful for anyone besides OP.

Comment: It is the interviewer's business car. Not mine. So I think that my question would be useful for the interviewer who is a supervisor in manufacturing department if he/she read this post. I don't need his/her business casrd. Could you get my question right?

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. If the manufacture manager happened to read this page, then it could be useful for two people.

Comment: *typo business card. But thank your for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Manufacturing Manager" is correct.

"Manufacture Manager" is incorrect, and fluent speakers will find it sounds wrong and unprofessional.

"Production Manager" is correct and also more common, but the individual's correct, official job title should be printed on the card.

Comment: That card was given to me as an interviewee by an interviewer at the end of the interview. Thank you for reminding that.a

Comment: How about the deputy of this title? "Deputy Manufacturing Manager" or "Manufacturing Deputy Manager" which one sounds good for fluent speakers?

Comment: Either is OK.   "Deputy Manager of Manufacturing" has the exact sense of the latter and might be preferred.